# How to determine points based on where the turtle is

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have a Python program and I need to get some statements so I can get points depending on the turtle's position in the target.

Here is my code:

```
import turtle
turtle.color("black")
turtle.circle(100)
print(turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor())
turtle.left(90)
turtle.penup()
turtle.forward(20)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(80)
print(turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor())
turtle.end_fill()
turtle.left(90)
turtle.penup()
turtle.forward(20)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.color("blue")
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(60)
print(turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor())
turtle.end_fill()
turtle.left(90)
turtle.penup()
turtle.forward(20)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.color("red")
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(40)
print(turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor())
turtle.end_fill()
turtle.left(90)
turtle.penup()
turtle.forward(20)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.color("yellow")
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(20)
print(turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor())
turtle.end_fill()
turtle.penup()
turtle.forward(20)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.color("green")
turtle.dot()
turtle.hideturtle()
```

Can you please give me help on how I get points based on the turtle's position?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of [Turtle graphics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) you can indeed find how to get the coordinates of the point where the turtle is currently located:

`turtle.position()` or `turtle.pos()` to get the `(x,y)` coordinates.

`turtle.xcor()` returns the turtle’s `x` coordinate.

`turtle.ycor()` returns the turtle’s `y` coordinate.

If you want to calculate a score depending on how close to the center of the drawn circle you are, simply calculate the distance of these coordinates to the distance of the coordinates of the center of the circle using a simple [mathematical formula](http://mathematical%20formula).